# std::chrono with NDK r10e could not be resolved

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, c++-chrono

Do not think I did not search, my Android project (on Eclipse) refuses to recognize std::chrono library. The include is OK in my header file :

```
#include <chrono>
```

But when I want use it :

```
using namespace std::chrono;
```

I have a : Symbol 'chrono' could not be resolved, and all the functions of chrono are unavailables.
So I use NDK r10e, I add some lines in my Application.mk, which now looks like this :

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-22
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++11
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

And in my Android.mk, I add :

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
```

It did not solve my problem. Any ideas ? Bad Eclipse configuration ?
After modifications in mk files, I have build and re-build my project.

Comment: If you use `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=gnu++11`, does it make any difference?

Comment: I've tried, no difference...

Answer (score 4):

This is known problem of GNU libstdc++ in Android NDK. It's built on top of very limited libc (Google's Bionic) and thus can't provide full C++ Standard Library functionality. In particular, `std::chrono` is almost completely disabled at build time, but not only `std::chrono`. There are many other classes and functions being disabled, so Google's NDK just don't support C++ fully.

You can switch to LLVM libc++ (`APP_STL := c++_static`), but it has experimental status in Google's Android NDK and is actually unstable (i.e. it cause crashes in the application even for completely standard C++ code). This instability is caused by the same reason as for GNU libstdc++ - i.e. because it's built on top of very limited libc.

I'd recommend switch to [CrystaX NDK](https://www.crystax.net/android/ndk) - alternative fork of Google's Android NDK, which I've started mainly to solve Google's NDK problems such as non-standard implementations of libc, libc++, etc. CrystaX NDK is developed to work as a drop-in replacement for Google's NDK (except for the fact that it provides fully standard-conforming low-level libraries). In CrystaX NDK, both GNU libstdc++ and LLVM libc++ are much more stable and fully conforming to C++ standard, at least at the same level as they conform to it on GNU/Linux. In particular, `std::chrono` is fully implemented there and works just fine. Also, in CrystaX NDK, you can use more recent compilers such as gcc-5.3 and clang-3.7, with better support of C++11 and C++14. I'd be happy if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work... std::chrono is always unknow. I am not comfortable with the c++ and CrystaX NDK crashes my app, it compiles (when I comment chrono) but does not run (file not found in NDK folder). However , I put it aside for the future, no time now.

Comment: It doesn't work when you switch to `c++_static` with Android NDK r10e? Or it doesn't work when you switch to CrystaX NDK? Anyway, in both cases I'm sure you're doing something wrong, just because `std::chrono` is definitely accessible in both cases. Probably something wrong with your Application.mk or Android.mk. I see you've postponed this, but if you decide to return back to it, first I'd recommend to build simple case and see if it works (it should, actually) and then switch to the more complicated case.

Comment: I just tried to switch to c++_static and my Eclipse has not supported it, I don't know why... About CrystaX, I'm sure you're right, I do something wrong, but what? Next time, I will do as you said : a simple example. Thanks